# Why does qwt-5.2 think I don't have QtSvg for x86_64 installed?

Tags: python, qt, macos, qgis

I'm trying to build [Quantum GIS](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS) from source but am running into a problem with one of the dependencies. I need to make and install [PyQwt](http://pyqwt.sourceforge.net/) and am getting the following compilation error:

```
$ make
g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -single_module -dynamiclib -o libqwt_designer_plugin.dylib obj/qwt_designer_plugin.o obj/qwt_designer_plotdialog.o obj/moc_qwt_designer_plugin.o obj/moc_qwt_designer_plotdialog.o obj/qrc_qwt_designer_plugin.o  -F/Library/Frameworks -L/Library/Frameworks -L../lib -lqwt -framework QtScript -framework QtCore -framework QtXml -framework QtGui -framework QtDesigner  
ld: file not found: QtSvg.framework/Versions/4/QtSvg for architecture x86_64
```

But if I run `file` command on QtSvg it tells me an x86_64 version is available:

```
$ file /Library/Frameworks/QtSvg.framework/Versions/4/QtSvg
/Library/Frameworks/QtSvg.framework/Versions/4/QtSvg: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Library/Frameworks/QtSvg.framework/Versions/4/QtSvg (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/Library/Frameworks/QtSvg.framework/Versions/4/QtSvg (for architecture i386):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

Is the problem because it's a Universal Binary?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the answer, but it looks on your link line that you don't have the QtSvg framework.

Have your tried adding `-framework QtSvg` on your link command ?

Comment: So far I am unable to figure out where in PyQwt to add frameworks for the Makefile.